# Filter posts in a WordPress loop with custom conditions

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am trying to build a post filter on my website. The post page needs to display two similar posts in the footer. But they have to meet certain conditions.

Conditions:

- **First condition:** A post has a number value(example:160) the two similar posts must be with in range of that value (example: if range is 10 a post with a 155 value would be in range of 160 ).
- **Second condition:** The similar posts are of the same category as the main post
- **Third condition:** If first two conditions fail, show predetermined post

Loops:

- if the **first condition** yields two results the loop must stop.
- if the **first condition** yields only one result the loop must continue with Second condition so two result get showen(the first post matching the first condition and the second post matching the **second condition**).
- if the **first condition** loop yields no results use the **second condition** for both posts.
- if **the first** and **the second** fail use **the third**.

Problems:

-The loop does not go trough all posts on the **first condition** it just goes through the first two lastest posts. How I can a make the conditions go through all posts first before continuing to the next condition?

Could someone explain to me how I can achieve my goal or atleast point me in the right direction. Thanks in advance

What I have got so far (width comments):

```
 <?php

    $orig_post = $post;
    $orig_city = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'property_city', true );

    // The post range value for main post
    $orig_area = (int)str_replace( array( ' ', ',', '.' ), '', get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'property_area', true ) );

    // The post category for main post
    $orig_category = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'property_category', array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) );


    $exclude_ids = array( $post->ID );

    // display all posts
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'property',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post__not_in' => $exclude_ids,

    );


    if ( $my_query->have_posts() && $orig_category ) {

        // Counter to display only two posts
        $counter = 0;
        while ( $my_query->have_posts() and $counter < 1 ) {
            $counter++;
            $my_query->the_post();
            $s_id = get_the_ID();

            // The range
            $s_area = (int)str_replace( array( ' ', ',', '.' ), '', get_post_meta( $s_id, 'property_area', true ) );
            $min = $orig_area - 10;
            $max = $orig_area + 10;

            // The first condition
            if ( ( $min <= $s_area ) and ( $s_area <= $max ) ) {
                echo 'first condition met';
                // The second condition
            } elseif ( $orig_category ) {
                echo 'second condition met';
                // The third condition
            } else {
                echo 'third condition met';
            }
            ?>

        <?php } ?>


    <?php }

    $post = $orig_post;
    wp_reset_query();
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Split to two loops:

```
$matches = [];
$total = [];

while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) {

    $post = $my_query->the_post();

    if (conformsToFirst($orig_post, $post)) 
        $matches[] = $post;
    else
        $total[] = $post;

    if (enough($orig_post, $matches))
        break;

}

if (!enough($orig_post, $matches)) {
    foreach ($total as $post) {
        if (conformsToSecond($orig_post, $post))
            $matches[] = $post;

        if (enough($orig_post, $matches))
            break;
    }

    if (!enough($orig_post, $matches)) {

        $matches = [pick_predefined_post()];
    }
}

// filtered results
// either [first_condition, first_condition]
// [first_condition, second_condition]
// [second_condition, second_condition, ]
// or [pick_predefined_post()-ed]
var_dump($matches);


function enough($to, $matches) {
    return count($matches) >= 2;
}

function conformsToFirst($to, $post) {
    //
    if (...)
        return true;

    return false;
}

function conformsToSecond($to, $post) {
    //
    if (...)
        return true;

    return false;
}
```